# New xml layout file is not being added to R.java

Tags: android, eclipse, r.java-file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/background1"
            tools:context="com.example.flavours.Category" >

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/homeimage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                 android:src="@drawable/ice1"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Each time I had a problem with R (R.id/layout) not been generated after change build target (6.0) to (5.0.1).
I already cleaned the project multiple times and whn i cleaned my project instantly i get error on "r"(R cannot be resolved to a variable) .I also import my (com.example.flavours.R;) but it remove whn i press Ctrl+shift+o.

Comment: Check all the contents in your res folder, e.g (drawable, values and layout) etc.

Comment: I experience this only when there is an error in my project which prevents R.java from being generated; usually an error reported by the aapt tool. This could be invalid XML or file names or other errors in the res/ directory. Check the output from aapt to see what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

i checked your code and i tested it ,
its true and works !

make sure that your new .xml file,has a valid name
valid name contains only

1. lowercase letters `a-z`
2. numbers `0-9` and they should`nt be in the first of file name.
3. underline `_`

also right click on the project and cleanup the source

```
Right Click On Project > Source > Clean Up...
```

or check build path for unwanted changes

```
Right Click On Project > Build Path > Configure Build Path...
```